# I need to fetch address against postcodes

Tags: php, curl, google-maps-api-3

I have database of postcodes now I need to fetach address against each postcode from google or some other service, can you please suggest me to do so ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fetch address against each postcode"? Can you give an example of exactly of what the input looks like, and what you want your output to be? Do you want a pure php solution?

Comment: Postcode is a part of an address... You can not retrieve a full address only from its postcode...

Comment: so can I get full address from latitude and longitude ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is called "geocoding."

Google Maps provides this service, you can read the documentation on how to use it from the Google Developer page for it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

---

You're able to call the API to get the information on an address, here is an example for getting the information for Melbourne, Australia (postcode 3000):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3000,Australia

---

You're then going to need to fetch the URL for each postcode you're looking up and run json_decode on the result. After that you can extract the information you want from it.

Here's a quick example I whipped up:

```php
<?php

// Get geocode information
function address_geocode_json($address)
{
    $geocode_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $geocode_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = ( $content ? json_decode( $content ) : false );

    return ( isset( $result->results ) ? $result->results : false );
}

// Get the postcode information-- you would use this within a loop
$postcode_information = address_geocode_json( '3000, Australia' );

// Here is the result structure
var_dump( $postcode_information );
```